# How do I retrieve a cookie from a NSURLResponse in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, cookies

I have a NSURLSession that calls `dataTaskWithRequest` in order to send a POST request. I modified the example I found [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/).

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
            
    // Other stuff goes here

})
```

I can't quite seem to get the header from the response. I know the cookie I want is somewhere in the header, because when I print out the response in the above code it shows me the cookie I want. But how do I properly get the cookie out of there?

I tried parsing the JSON, but I couldn't figure out how to get the NSURLResponse into NSData for something like this:

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ResponseData, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Setup a NSMutableURLRequest to your desired URL to call along with a "POST" HTTP Method

var aRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL GOES HERE")!)
var aSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
aRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// Pass your username and password as parameters in your HTTP Request's Body

var params = ["username" : "ENTER YOUR USERNAME" , "password" : "ENTER YOUR PASSWORD"] as Dictionary <String, String>
var err: NSError?
aRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)

// The following header fields are added so as to get a JSON response

aRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
aRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

// Setup a session task which sends the above request

var task = aSession.dataTaskWithRequest(aRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

     // Save the incoming HTTP Response

     var httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

     // Since the incoming cookies will be stored in one of the header fields in the HTTP Response, parse through the header fields to find the cookie field and save the data

     let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(httpResponse.allHeaderFields, forURL: response.URL!) as! [NSHTTPCookie]

     NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(cookies as [AnyObject], forURL: response.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)

})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Hi :)! It would be nice if you could add a short explanation to your code so that others can understand it with more ease.

Comment: @JakobRunge Hi, I've added comments on the code for easier understanding! Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 update : Gives you a [HTTPCookie]

```
    if let url = urlResponse.url,
       let allHeaderFields = urlResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String : String] {
       let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: allHeaderFields, for: url)
    }
```

Comment: … and to store those cookies for future requests:

`HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast your NSURLResponse to a NSHTTPURLResponse and then use the property called 'allHeaderFields'. That property is a Dictionary, where you should find your Cookie.

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to let me do that. When I try `let someResponse : NSHTTPURLResponse = response` it gives me an error saying "NSURLResponse is not convertible to type NSHTTPURLResponse."

Comment: let someResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse

Answer (score 0):

```
            let cookies: [NSHTTPCookie]?
            if let responseHeaders = response.allHeaderFields as? [String:String] {
                cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaders, forURL:request.URL!)
                NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(cookies!, forURL: response.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
            }
```